# Silverlight project referencing PCL exception: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Xml.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, portable-class-library

I have a Silverlight 5 project which referencing portable class library project.
When my silverlight code trying to use serialization logic defined in PCL project I get following exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Xml.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Stacktrace shows that error occurs in following constructor:

```
    private readonly XmlWriterSettings m_WriterSettings;

    private XmlSerializer(XmlWriterSettings settings = null)
    {
        m_WriterSettings = settings;
    }
```

How can I fix it?

(Sorry, English isn't my native language)

Comment: I repro, looks like a bug to me.  It should have been redirected to System.Xml.dll.  You can report the bug at connect.microsoft.com

Answer (score 0):

what is this

```
private XmlSerializer(XmlWriterSettings settings = null)
{
    m_WriterSettings = settings;
}
```

a constructor ?

as in "your' yourNameSpace.XmlSerializer  (try renaming it, or create an alias?) 
 collision?

what profile the pcl targets ?

check this [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566193/filenotfoundexception-in-portable-class-library) and the answer (there is an Update for the .NET Framework 4)

if you are uptodate 
did you hard referenced to "System.Xml.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0"

I'm resolving   Version 4.0.0.0,  or 5.0.5.0

whats your using's declaration?

I tried calling the newly created pcl from Net 4 /4.5  and Silverlight 5  with a couple of profiles on VS2013 and VS2012 and I had no problems